# Command line semaphore utility

Tags: command-line, synchronization, semaphore, utility

I want to write a command line utility that can be used to synchronize the execution off programs in different consoles.

```
Console A: 
$ first_program && semaphore -signal

Console B:
$ semaphore -wait && second_program
```

The first program takes a long take to complete. The second program can only start when the first program has finished.

Which synchronization object do I need to implement this?

Comment: I have written a [command line utility](http://stefan-klinger.de/tools/sem/) for named Linux semaphores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use Python for this. Considering you are using Unix, try this:

First, create a pipe for the semaphore.

```
mknod /tmp/semaphore p
```

Then, the programs:

```
Console A:
$ first_program && echo a > /tmp/semaphore

Console B:
$ read < /tmp/semaphore && second_program
```

Actually, this method works both ways. The read will block until there is a write, and vice versa.

Comment: Was just about to write exact same thing using `mkfifo`  :)

Answer (score 0):

If they're on the same machine the first program can touch a temporary file.

There is a Gamin module in python that will allow your second program to sit there and wait while not tying up resources.  It isn't a busy wait, or doing anything with sleep or stuff like that.